# Firebase complex query - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got instagram like app.
I got firebase as backend which has :

post node - contains all the posts from different users
[post_id
post_user
post_name
post_content]

**Problem:** 
I want to get the posts only from the users which I have followed.

**My Steps:**

1. I got list of following users_id in array

   ```
   followersIds
   ```
2. I want to know if I can make query like

   ```
   getFollowersList { (followersIds) in

       print(followersIds)

       self.postRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "user").queryEqual(toValue: followersIds).queryLimited(toLast: limit).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
           if snapshot.value is NSNull { completion(nil); return}
           else {
               let dict = snapshot.value as! [String:Any]
               self.mapDictionaryToArrayOfPost(dict: dict, completion: { (posts) in
                   completion(posts)
               })
           }
       }) { (error) in
           debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
       }

   }
   ```

**ISSUE:**
Firebase can't accept array as parameter in queryEqual()

I can do this filter by filtering in the app but i want to query firebase and get the result .
Beacause filtering in the app is not a good thing.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this query in one go in Firebase. As is common in most NoSQL solutions, you should model the data in a way that allows the use-cases that your app needs.

This means that: if you want to retrieve all posts from people you follow in one go, you should keep a list of all posts from people you follow in the database. Since you seem to be building something like a social network, that means that you're essentially building each user's wall:

```
following
  uid1
    uid2: true // so uid1 follows uid2 and uid3
    uid3: true
  uid3
    uid2: true // and uid3 follows uid2
posts
    post1 
      author: uid2 // uid2 has made a post
      title: "...." 
    post2 
      author: uid3 // uid3 has made a post
      title: "...." 
wall
  uid1
    post1: true
    post2: true
  uid3
    post1: true
```

So in this model we keep the key of each post of a user that you follow under `/wall/myuid`. Now you can easily get the list of posts to show the wall of a specific user. And from that you can loop over the keys and load each of them. The latter is not a slow operation on Firebase, since it pipelines the requests. See [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).

This type of data duplication is very common in NoSQL databases such as Firebase, which is why we cover it in our [documentation on structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#fanout), in our [firefeed demo app](https://firefeed.io/) and in our new video series [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).